# Log2 vs Quantile normalization

Tags: human-biology

I am learning normalizations, I wonder when log2 and quantile normalization is used in each situation, may I ask if there is any material that compare these two types especially in microarray expression matrix for differentially expressed gene analysis? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Biology but about statistics.

Comment: Note that the tag 'human-biology' that you chose does not apply